# How to connect Node.js app to database when they are running in separate Docker containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, neo4j

I have these containers running:

[image]

I am able to visit node app at `localhost:49160` and database at `localhost:7474` as expected.

However, the node app can't seem to actually connect to the database. I get this error when I try:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7474
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

This normally means it can't find the database at that host:port.

Again, I am able to visit `127.0.0.1:7474` and clearly see the database is running.

I have also tried to connecting to `0.0.0.0:7474`, but that didn't work either.

**There are no issues when I run the node app locally + database in docker container, but this problem occurs when I also run the node app in a docker container.**

What host and port should be database be available at (what should I connect to?), and what am I probably missing or doing wrong?

**Dockerfile for node-app**

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

**docker neo4j run cmd**

```
docker run -d -e NEO4J_AUTH=none \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins \
    neo4j:3.1.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am describing one way of doing it, and there might be other possible ways which I am currently unaware of. Since the `links` are deprecated now, we can use networks to connect one container to another.

First of all we create a network with this command:

`docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 isolated_nw`

And then we connect the mysql container by assigning it an IP address from the network we created. And yeah, we specify the network too. This command does the required purpose:

```
docker run -itd --rm \
  --network=isolated_nw \
  --ip=172.25.3.3 \
  --name=mysql \
  --volume "$(pwd)/database/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" mysql
```

Now we have got our mysql container running and connected to the `isolated_nw` we created. Its time to get our other container connected to the same network and access the mysql container. Adding `--network=isolated_nw` flag while running a container adds the container to the network. And we shall use this flag while running our other container which requires to access mysql.

Now  it is done! Inside this other container we can access mysql container at the IP address we allocated, i.e, at 172.25.3.3.  An implementation of these things can be seen [here](https://github.com/reactome/container/blob/develop/java-application-builder/build_webapps.sh).