# What is the proper way to write docker for following app structure?

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

I have 3 nodejs microservices running on nodejs. one of which runs in a seperate subdomain and the other 2 are routed based on path. My Docker file is as below

```
FROM node:latest     

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app                 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/           
RUN npm install      

COPY . /usr/src/app  
EXPOSE 9000          
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The port is different for each image. After this i have an nginx running on bare metal server with all configurations for reverse proxy. I know that this is not the best way to go around. How can i have 3 seperate instances run and listen on the same port ?

Also for database linking i am using `--link` flag but that is shown to be as depreciated in the docs, what is the right way to go around that ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197727/6207775) may help you in setting up connections in your container. For more details, see [docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of NGiNX, use [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/): it will adapt its reverse proxy rule depending on the containers it discovers through consul.
See "[Traefik Swarm cluster](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm/)" in order to setup a cluster.

You can then declare your database in order for said base to run always on the same node, using [service constrains](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints-constraint).

See for instance "[Running a MongoDB Replica Set on Docker 1.12 Swarm Mode: Step by Step](https://medium.com/@kalahari/running-a-mongodb-replica-set-on-docker-1-12-swarm-mode-step-by-step-a5f3ba07d06e)":

> The basic plan is to define each member of the replica set as a separate service, and use constraints to prevent swarm orchestration moving them away from their data volumes

For instance:

```
docker@manager1:~$ docker node update --label-add mongo.replica=1 $(docker node ls -q -f name=manager1)

docker service create --replicas 1 --network mongo \
  --mount type=volume,source=mongodata1,target=/data/db \
  --mount type=volume,source=mongoconfig1,target=/data/configdb \
  --constraint 'node.labels.mongo.replica == 1' \
  --name mongo1 mongo:3.2 mongod --replSet example
```