# Docker-compose access container with service name in python file?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I have a two container and How I can access another container in python file with django web server

## Docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:

  web:
    build: ./web/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
    volumes:
      - ./web:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    networks:
      - dock_net
    container_name: con_web
    depends_on:
      - "api"
    links:
      - api
  api:
    build: ./api/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    networks:
      - dock_net
    container_name: con_api

networks:
  dock_net:
      driver: bridge
```

## Python File:

I can get mail_string  from form

```
   mail = request.POST.get('mail_string', '') 
   url = 'http://con_api:8000/api/'+mail+'/?format=json'
   resp = requests.get(url=url)         
   return HttpResponse(resp.text)
```

I request api container and get value but  I dont know ip address

Comment: yeah that's good! But am confused if it is a status update or a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

In your python file, you can use `url = 'http://api/'+mail+'/?format=json'`. This will enable you to access the url you are trying to get request from.

**Original Answer**

If the two containers are independent, then you can create a [network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/) and when you make both the containers a part of same network then you can access them using their hostname which you can specify by [`--hostname=HOSTNAME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/).

---

Another easy way is to use docker-compose file which creates a network by default and all the services declared in the file are a part of that network. By that you can access other services by their service name. Simply like http://container1/ when your docker-compose file is like this:

```
version: '3'
services:

  container1:
    image: some_image

  container2:
    image: another_or_same_image
```

Now enter into container2 by:

`docker exec -it container2 /bin/bash`

and run `ping http://contianer1`

You will receive packets and therefore be able to access other container.

Comment: I can this but I can't this in python file

Comment: The answer I gave is complete and you are getting a URL which you can use in your python file. If you are not familiar with docker-compose, and running container using docker run I have given another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197727/6207775) using the containers only.

Comment: Can you give me example? I try getting ip address  with service in python file but print service_name

Comment: Update the question and include how you are trying, I'll be able to help you better if I know what you want to do. Include how you are running containers and also include what you have written in python to access other container.

Comment: But python file in con_web container , api is con_api ?

Comment: we don't use container name, we use service name to access the container.